# Date getTime() returns various values on separate machines

Tags: javascript, date

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), `new Date()`:

> creates a JavaScript Date instance that represents a single
>   moment in time. Date objects are based on a time value that is the
>   number of milliseconds since 1 January, 1970 UTC

when it comes to `getTime()`:

> Returns the numeric value of the specified date as the number of
>   milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC (negative for prior
>   times).

Why the statement:

```
new Date(new Date(1, 0, 1).setFullYear(1)).getTime();
```

which suppose to return the number of milliseconds from January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC to 01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM, gives different values on separate machines, e.g. `-62135600400000` and `-62135596800000`? Does the local timezones (or system times?) affect this logic somehow?

Comment: `console.log(new Date(new Date(1, 0, 1).setFullYear(1)));` results in `Mon Jan 01 1 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)` So yes, timezones make a difference when you create a date in that manner.

Comment: @epascarello: On my local Node.js the same statement gives: Mon Jan 01 1 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time). Isn't that the same?

Comment: Midnight in New York and midnight in Warsaw are obviously not the same...

Comment: `console.log(new Date("Mon Jan 01 1 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)")` is
`Sun Dec 31 2000 18:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)`

Comment: @jcaron: Not the same but the specification says about UTC, and the difference from Jan 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC should be constant no matter the timezone, no?

Comment: OK, let me ask you: on this date, what is the time difference between midnight UTC and midnight New York time? Ditto for the time difference between midnight UTC and midnight Warsaw time? Are they the same? No.

Comment: @jcaron: Thanks for patience. It's correct. I've just noticed that the Date constructor, when invoked with multiple arguments, represents local time, not UTC one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's specified in the documentation:

> Note: Where Date is called as a constructor with more than one
>   argument, **the specifed arguments represent local time**. If UTC is
>   desired, use new Date(Date.UTC(...)) with the same arguments.

Comment: Indeed, I've missed that an was a bit confused.

Comment: It would be good to include a link to "the documentation". ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's because of timezones.

Using:

```
new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute, second))
```

you can create a Date-object from a specific UTC time.

[mdn Date.UTC()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC)